# Copy value from one input into multiple inputs using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I want to be able to copy the value from singleStakesBox into each of the stakebox inputs. I have tried to do this by using GetElementById but it only works for the first stakebox.

Javascript

```
<script>
$('#singleStakesBox').keyup(function () {
    document.getElementById("stakebox").value = document.getElementById('singleStakesBox').value;
    calcTotalStake();
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="singlesStakeBox" id="singleStakesBox" />

<td><input type="text" class="stakebox" id="stakebox" data-stake="stakebox" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="stakebox" id="stakebox" data-stake="stakebox" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="stakebox" id="stakebox" data-stake="stakebox" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="stakebox" id="stakebox" data-stake="stakebox" /></td>
```

Comment: four inputs having same ID?

Comment: Id should be unique. Or use class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use jquery for that:

```
<script>
$('#singleStakesBox').keyup(function () {
    $(".stakebox").val($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName("stakebox");
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    input[i].value = document.getElementById('singleStakesBox').value;
```

Or simply use jquery:

```
$(".stakebox").val($('#singleStakesBox').val());
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ox7o3u1h/)

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns an array. So this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
$('#singleStakesBox').keyup(function () {
    var stakeVal = $('#singleStakesBox').val();
    $('.stakebox').val(stakeVal);
});
```

and use `class` attribute rather than `id` to reflect values across all the elements. the `id` attribute is meant to be unique where as the `class` attribute holds all the shared properties